# Algorithm to select a random bit string with constraints

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms

## Problem Description

Given $a, b, n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a < b < n$.

Let $M$ be the set of all possible bit strings of length $n$ which begin and end with one and have at least $a$ and at most $b$ zeros between every pair of successive ones:
$$
AZ_s(x, y) :\equiv s_{x} = s_{x+1} = \ldots = s_{y} = 0 \\
M := \left\{s \in \{0,1\}^n \mid s_1 = s_n = 1 \land \\
\forall i \in \{1, 2, \ldots n-1\}: s_i = 1 \Rightarrow AZ_s(i+1, \min\{i+a, n\}) \land \lnot AZ_s(i+1, \min\{i+b, n\})
\right\}
$$
For example, with $a=1, b=3, n=8$, the set of possible bit strings is $M = \{10001001, 10010001, 10010101, 10100101, 10101001\}$.

I need a fast algorithm which gets $a$, $b$ and $n$, and returns one random element of $M$ with uniform probability.

Here $a$ and $b$ are small constants and "fast" refers to the asymptotic time with respect to $n$. If possible, the algorithm's execution time should be polynomial in $n$ and not probabilistic.

There may be existing solutions for my problem but I don't know what I would need to search for to find them. Suggestions and links are welcome.

## My Solution Approaches

I've thought about ways to solve the problem but couldn't find a solution which fulfils all criteria yet.

### Greedy Probabilistic Algorithm

This algorithm repeatedly appends zeros followed by a one to the bit string $s$ until the length of $s$ is $n$ or longer. If $s$ is too long, it truncates $s$ at the beginning and then goes back to the appending phase. A result is found once $s$ has length $n$.

Let $|s|$ denote the current length of the bit string.

1. Initialise the bit string to $s = 1$
2. Select $k$ randomly from $\{a, a+1, \ldots, b\}$ and append $k$ zeros followed by a one to $s$
3. If $|s| < n$, goto 2
4. If $|s| = n$, return $s$
5. Remove the prefix `^10*` (a one followed by one or more zeros) from $s$
6. goto 3

I doubt (but haven't proven) that this algorithm selects each element from $M$ with the same probability. Perhaps it is possible to modify this algorithm to fulfil this criteria; for example it could skip step 4 with a probability which depends on the current number of ones in $s$.

### Enumeration

With an ordering of the elements of $M$, each $s \in M$ can be bijectively associated with a number in $\{1, 2, \ldots, |M|\}$. It may be possible to create an algorithm which selects such a number randomly and returns the corresponding bit string.

Consider the example from above: $a=1, b=3, n=8$, $M = \{10001001, 10010001, 10010101, 10100101, 10101001\}$.

- Partition $M$ into $M_k$ such that $M_k$ contains all bit strings with $k$ ones. Here: $M_3 = \{10001001, 10010001\}, M_4 = \{10010101, 10100101, 10101001\}$
- Partition $M_k$ into $M_{k,G}$ such that $G$ is a multiset which contains the lengths of consecutive zeros. Here: $M_{3, \{2,3\}} = \{10001001, 10010001\}, M_{4, \{1,1,2\}} = \{10010101, 10100101, 10101001\}$. Note that in general there can be multiple $G$ for one $k$; for example $Y_3 = \{1001001, 1010001, 1000101\} \Rightarrow Y_{3,\{2,2\}} = \{1001001\}, Y_{3,\{1,3\}} = \{1010001, 1000101\}$.
- $|M_{k,G}|$ is the number of tuples which map to $G$ if the order of their elements is ignored.

Omitting the details, an algorithm could do following:

1. Calculate $|M|$ and select $x \in \{1, 2, \ldots, |M|\}$ with uniform probability
2. Find $k$ such that $\sum_{i<k} |M_i| < x \leq \sum_{i \leq k} |M_i|$ and set $x_k := x - \sum_{i<k} |M_i|$
3. Similarly to step 2, find $G$ and calculate $x_{k,G}$. This requires an ordering of the sets $M_{k,G}$ with respect to $G$.
4. Return the $x_{k,G}$-th element of $M_{k,G}$, which is the $x$-th element of $M$. This requires an ordering of the elements in $M_{k,G}$.

I haven't found a fast version of this algorithm yet; for example, I don't know how to calculate $|M|$ in constant time.

### Graph Colouring

It could be possible to create a graph where each $s_i$ is represented by a node and the edges represent the constraints for the bit string $s \in M$.
The edges would be set such that there is a bijective mapping between the valid colourings of this graph and $M$. For example, due to the edges, the nodes corresponding to $s_1$ and $s_n$ must always have the same colour in any colouring. The graph can have more than $n$ nodes.

An algorithm which returns one of all possible colourings with uniform probability would solve the problem but I think that this algorithm would be slow.

### Additional Algorithms Mentioned for Completeness

#### Brute-Force Probabilistic Algorithm

It should be possible to repeatedly select a random $s \in \{0,1\}^n$ until $s \in M$ holds. However, for big $n$, $M$ is very large and the success probability is low, so this algorithm would be too slow.

#### Explicit Calculation of $M$

It should be possible to calculate all possible elements of $M$ explicitly and then return one of them randomly. However, for large $M$, this simple algorithm is too slow.

Comment: In your examples, all ones are isolated, but I don't see that in the definition.

Comment: Is there a reason why you imposed $a < b$ and not just $a \leq b$?

Comment: I've defined the set $M$ with first order logic. In this definition the $AZ_s(x,y)$ predicate is true if and only if in $s$ the bits starting with the $x$-th bit and ending with the $y$-th bit are all zero, for example $AZ_{100001}(2,4)$ is true because the second, third and fourth bit are zero.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: In the example, all ones are isolated because for all positions $i$ where the bit string has a one ($s_i = 1$), the following bits must be zero at least up to the position $i+a$ ($AZ_s(i+1, min\{i+a,n\})$). $a$ is always at least one and I've added the minimum because $s_y$ is undefined for $y>n$.

Comment: @D.W.: The condition on the number of zeros refers to every pair of successive ones. My formal definition of $M$ with first order logic is directly below that sentence.

Comment: @Stef: There is no special reason for $a < b$. $a=b$ would be a trivial case where $M$ is either empty or has one element, so I've omitted this case. Furthermore, $M$ can be empty for certain values of $a$, $b$ and $n$ (e.g. $a=2, b=3, n=6$), in which case no algorithm exists to solve my problem; I didn't mention this for brevity.

Comment: That still does not answer my question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If I understand you correctly, the presence of a one which is not isolated means that there are two ones next to each other.

Proof by contradiction:

Assume $s \in M$ and $s$ has two consecutive ones, i.e. $\exists i \in \{1,2, \ldots, n-1\}: s_i = s_{i+1} = 1$.

Comment: Consider a superset $K$, $M \subset K$. Since $s \in M$, $s \in K$ must also hold.
$
M \\
= \{s \in \{0,1\}^n \mid s_1 = s_n = 1 \land \\
\forall i \in \{1, 2, \ldots n-1\}: s_i = 1 \Rightarrow AZ_s(i+1, \min\{i+a, n\}) \land \lnot AZ_s(i+1, \min\{i+b, n\})
\} \\
\subset \{s \in \{0,1\}^n \mid
\forall i \in \{1, 2, \ldots n-1\}: s_i = 1 \Rightarrow AZ_s(i+1, i+1)\} \\
= \{s \in \{0,1\}^n \mid
\forall i \in \{1, 2, \ldots n-1\}: s_i = 1 \Rightarrow s_{i+1} = 0\} \\
= \{s \in \{0,1\}^n \mid
\lnot (\exists i \in\{1, 2, \ldots n-1\}: s_i = 1 \land s_{i+1} = 1)\} \\
= K
$

Comment: The condition that a bit string has two consecutive ones is negated in the definition of $K$, so $s$ cannot be in $K$ or a subset of $K$.

Comment: Do you mean that all ones must be isolated ?

Comment: Yes, due to the definition of $M, a$ and $n$, all ones must be isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done using a bit of dynamic programming. First, let us try to solve a different problem, which is computing $|M|$ given $n$, $a$ and $b$.

Denote $f(n, a, b)$ this number. Note that a string in $M$ is composed of a $1$, followed by a sequence of substrings of the form $0^k1$, with $k\in \{a, a+1, …, b\}$. Using that fact, considering the length of the last substring, we conclude that for $n>1$:

$$f(n, a, b) = \sum\limits_{k=a}^bf(n - k - 1, a, b)$$

The base cases are $f(1, a, b) = 1$ (only one string of length $1$) and $f(n, a,b) = 0$ if $n<0$.

Since we can assume $0 \leqslant a \leqslant b \leqslant n$ without loss of generality, this gives a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm to compute $f(n, a, b)$.

Now back to the random selection. In the same way as previously, we will create the string backward:

- if $n = 1$, return $1$;
- otherwise, pick $k\in \{a, a+1, …, b\}$ with probability $\frac{f(n-k-1, a, b)}{f(n, a, b)}$ and return recursively a random string of length $n-k-1$ followed by $0^k1$.

With memoisation of the computation of $f(n, a, b)$, this algorithm is also in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

Comment: I think if $a$ and $b$ are small constants, the algorithm is even in $O(n)$, so it solves my problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to improve the time to $O(n \log(n))$ even if $a$ and $b$ are not constant.

$f(n, a, b)$ may be calculated in constant time without the big sum:
$$
f(n, a, b) - f(n-1, a, b) = \sum_{k=a}^b f(n-k-1, a, b) - \sum_{k=a}^{b} f(n-1-k-1, a, b) = f(n-a-1, a, b) - f(n-b-2, a, b) \\
f(n, a, b) = f(n-1, a, b) + f(n-a-1, a, b) - f(n-b-2, a, b)
$$
(additional base cases are needed so that, for example, $f(2, a, b) = 0$ holds)
This leads to $O(n)$ for the first part of the algorithm.

Comment: Cumulative probabilities could be used for the random selection:
$$
\forall i < 1: F(i, a, b) = 0 \\
F(n, a, b) = F(n-1, a, b) + f(n, a, b)
$$
With this pick $x \in \{F(n-b-2,a,b)+1, \ldots, F(n-a-1,a,b)\}$ with uniform probability and find $k$ with binary search such that $F(n-k-1,a,b) < x \leq F(n-k,a,b)$ holds.
The second part of the algorithm is then in $O(n \log(n))$; perhaps the expected time is even in $o(n \log(n))$.

Note that there may be mistakes in my formulas.